# Add Foreign Key relationships as bulk operation

Tags: mysql

I've inherited a database with hundreds of tables. Tables may have implicit FK relations that are not explicitly defined as such.

I would like to write a script or query that would be able to do this for all tables. For instance, if a table has a field called `user_id`, then we know there's a FK relationship with the users table on the id column. Is this even doable?

Comment: It is doable. Output the table schema into a file and use regular expressions to parse it. But it may be faster to do it manually :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible but I would want to explore more.  Many folks design relational databases without foreign keys especially in the MySQL world.  Also people reuse column names in different tables in the same schema (often with less than optimal results).  Double check that what you think is a foreign key can be used that way (same data type, width, collation/character set, etc.).

Then i would recommend you copy the tables to a test machine and start doing your ALTER TABLES to add foreign keys.  Test like heck.